# What charge does muon have?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, standard-model, leptons

I have a simple $\mu$-meso atom model. Kernel is just one proton and on orbit there's one muon, which is 210 times heavier than electron. What charge does it have? I checked some tables about muons and all of them have 0, +e, -e charges.
Should I just denote it's charge as $\mu_{-}$ or I could compute it precisely.

Comment: The charge of a muon is $-e$.

Comment: Be careful about the terminology. A [meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson) normally means a particle made up from a quark and an anti-quark. These are completely different from muons, though historically muons were described as mesons, hence the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, made some edits.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon): “A muon is an elementary particle similar to the electron, with an electric charge of −1 $e$ …”

Comment: there is no neutral muon (maybe you looked at pions?), anyway, a $\mu^0$ would mean it is certainly no cousin of the electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The muon has an electric charge of $-1e = -1.6\times10^{−19}$C, just like the electron.

Note that while historically, muons were called mu mesons, that name shouldn't be used anymore as mesons today denote composite particles made up of equal numbers of quarks and antiquarks.